# Приращение переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, почему неправильно работает скрипт:

```
guides = 0;
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 87) {guides++};
    if (guides & 1) {
        $("#grid-bg").css("background-image","none");
        $(".parallax__layer--back").css("background-image","none");
    };
    if (guides & 2) {
        $("#grid-bg").css("background-image","url(grid.png)");
        $(".parallax__layer--back").css("background-image","url(bg-new.svg)");
    };
});
```

Смысл в том, что при нажатии на клавишу W (код 87) должен пропасть фон, а при повторном нажатии появится. И при первых двух нажатиях всё работаешь как надо, но в последующем приходится нажимать на W по нескольку раз чтобы фон пропал. С чем это связано?

Comment: как ты думаешь, что делает оператор & в выражении `guides & 1` и `guides & 2`?

Comment: проверяет на чётность

Comment: не угадал. Фактически это проверяется выставлен ли в числе первый или второй бит. Например для 4 (100) второй бит не выставлен и 4&2 вернет 0, хотя должен был вернуть true, так как число четное

Comment: на самом деле все решается заменой второго If На else

Comment: Если нужен переключатель, то приращение вообще не нужно. Нужно `guides = !guides` и проверка `if (!guides) ... else ...` Или даже тернарный оператор в двух местах вместо `if ... else ...`